# SQL - Group by a column (non primary key) to have one line by value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL and struggling with finding a valid SQL query.

I have an entity table like :

```
id, user_id
```

where a `user_id` can have many entity ids.

I wanted to group records by user id (which is not the primary key of the table) to have something like :

```
user_id   array_ids
100068050,{418626, 153449}
100068230,{117511, 66282, 107948, 172525, 97024}
```

I need one line per user id.

I did :

```
SELECT tab.user_id, ARRAY_AGG(tab.id) AS array_ids
FROM table tab
GROUP BY tab.id
```

but got this :

```
user_id   array_ids
100068050,{418626}
100068050,{153449}
100068230,{117511}
100068230,{66282}
100068230,{107948}
100068230,{172525}
100068230,{97024}
```

I tried also grouping by user id but when I introduced an order by another column, I got

> [42803] ERROR: column "ss.email_notification" must appear in the GROUP
> BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

My full query is this :

```
SELECT tab.user_id, ARRAY_AGG(tab.id) AS array_ids
FROM table tab
GROUP BY tab.user_id
ORDER BY tab.user_id ASC, tab.email_notification DESC NULLS LAST
```

Probably I'm missing something and doing stag wrong. Could you please point me to ideas / concepts / commands that would help me achieve this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a typo I guess. You want one result line per user_id, so you must `GROUP BY user_id`, not by id.

Comment: Actually I tried that but when I introduced an order by another column, I got 



`[42803] ERROR: column "ss.email_notification" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

My full query is this :


`SELECT tab.user_id, ARRAY_AGG(tab.id) AS array_ids FROM table tab
GROUP BY tab.user_id
ORDER BY tab.user_id ASC, tab.email_notification DESC NULLS LAST`

Comment: As a user_id can be multiple times in the table, we can find the same user_id with different email_notifications. By which of these do you want to sort your results? Maybe by `MIN(tab.email_notification )` or `MAX(tab.email_notification )`.

Comment: Just a note, but tables have _columns_, not fields.